# Не передаются данные

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

Всем привет. Начинаю осваивать JQuery и AJAX. Написал функцию для парсера. В которой нужно передать ID в качестве параметра PHP файлу с помощью аякса. А на выходе разобрать содержимое XML файла по полям. Вот её сцеарий:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function kp_info ( )
    {
        var url = document.getElementById("kp_url").value;
        ShowLoading("");

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
                url: "engine/ajax/kp_parser.php",
                data: "url="+url,
                dataType: "xml", 
                success: function(xml) {

                jQuery(xml).find("site").each(

                    function() {

                    year = jQuery(this).find("year").text(),
                    actors = jQuery(this).find("actors").text();
                    ganre = jQuery(this).find("ganre").text();
                    descr = jQuery(this).find("descr").text();
                    director = jQuery(this).find("director").text();
                    name = jQuery(this).find("name").text();
                    or_name = jQuery(this).find("or_name").text();

                        $('#name').val(name);
                        $('#year').val(year);
                        $('#or_name').val(or_name);                         
                        $('#ganre').val(ganre);
                        $('#director').val(director);
                        $('#actors').append(actors);
                        $('#descr').append(descr);

                   }
                );

                }

            });

        HideLoading("");

        return false;

    }
</script>
```

Этот скрипт работает в старой версии Оперы, но в современных браузерах это делать отказывается. В консоли хрома выдаёт следующее:

> event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future.

Пожалуйста подскажите как привести его к работе во всех браузерах. Если нужно, могу заплатить.

Comment: Помогло! Спасибо большое. Надо бы наверное ваш комент пихнуть в ответ, чтоб вопрос считать закрытым.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такая ошибка - признак слишком старой версии jQuery. Попробуйте для начала его обновить.